# Why does findViewById returning null when searching for the RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, container-view

Why is  `val rv: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.material_list_rv)` returning null?

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var adaptor: MaterialListAdaptor = MaterialListAdaptor()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                setReorderingAllowed(true)
                add<MaterialListFragment>(R.id.fragment_container_view)
            }
        }

        initRecyclerView()
        setRecyclerViewData()

    }

    private fun initRecyclerView(){
        val rv: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.material_list_rv)
        rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        rv.adapter = adaptor
    }

    private fun setRecyclerViewData(){
        val l = DataSource.createMaterialList()
        adaptor.setDataSet(l)
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MaterialListFragment**

```
class MaterialListFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_material_list, container, false)
    }
}
```

**fragment_material_list**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MaterialListFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/material_list_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/material_list_rv_list_item" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

You placed the call to `findViewById` in `MainActivity.onCreate`. It's too early for that, the Fragment's view hasn't been created at that point.

You should be looking for the view in your `MaterialListFragment`. If you call `findViewById` in `onCreateView`, it will work. Like this:

```
val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_material_list, container, false)
val rv = root.findViewById(R.id. material_list_rv)

// Do whatever (eg assign rv to a field in the Fragment to use it later)

return root
```

#### Some advice

Even if your code worked, try to have Activities, Fragments and custom Views manage their own children.

If the upper containers dive deep into their children, it's *very* easy to make mistakes (like the one here!) and you lose the ability to update internal details of Fragments and Views without breaking the containing Activity.

#### Activity/Fragment lifecycle chart

To orient yourself, keep this in mind (though this diagram is *EXTREMELY* simplified):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer lead me to this link https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for RecylerView in MainActivity, where it does not exist.
Instead you should try to access it in FragmentActivity.